# C++ on NAO Robot - How to run my C++ code?

Tags: c++, nao-robot

in "Choregraphe", it is easy to use python to make the robot do something and show it in the robot view but how about C++? if i have a "main.cpp", how can i "put" it in "Choregraphe" and run it, so that i can see the result in the robot view?
i guest it is using python to call dll written in C++?
sorry about my question, because i am newbie so i don't understand a lot
‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎

Comment: Hi! It would probably be helpful to others if you could add some of your source to the question.

Comment: Unm...NAO is a robot which run his own OS and Choregraphe is the software which programming the robot, but Choregraphe can only run python code, i would like to know how to run C++ code

Comment: Ups, sorry I didn't get that.

Comment: oh thanks a lot i have just solve it!!!!!!!!!!!!! thank you so much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: You need to cross-compile the c++ code, then you can upload it to the robot, using choregraphe or scp-like tools.
But it's not that simple, hopefully there's some ressources in the documentation...

Answer (score 0):

Without a further description of exactly what you need, as long as you can compile C++ in the NAO OS, you should be able to write whatever objects you would like in C++ and then wrap them with a python interface. Check out this resource

http://intermediate-and-advanced-software-carpentry.readthedocs.org/en/latest/c++-wrapping.html